# How to linearize the product of two binary variables?

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, binary-variable

Suppose we have two binary variables $x$ and $y$. How can we linearize the product $xy$?

Comment: This quickreference did help me very well to model logical equations as linear constraints: https://msi-jp.com/xpress/learning/square/10-mipformref.pdf. Since your case is a simple _and_.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This scenario can be linearized by introducing a new binary variable $z$ which represents the value of $x y$. Notice that the product of $x$ and $y$ can only be non-zero if both of them equal one, thus $x = 0$ and/or $y = 0$ implies that $z$ must equal zero.

$$z \leq x\\z \leq y$$

The only thing left is to force $z$ to equal one if the product of $x$ and $y$ equals one, which only happens if both of them equal one.

$$ z \geq x + y - 1. $$

**The general case with $n$ binary variables**

This method can also directly be applied to the general case where we have the product of multiple binary variables. Suppose we have $n$ binary variables $x_i$ and we want to linearize the product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n x_i.
$$
Then you can introduce a new binary variable $z$ that represents the value of this product and model it by introducing the following constraints
$$
\begin{align}
z &\leq x_i \quad \text{ for } i = 1, \ldots, n.\\
z &\geq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (n-1).
\end{align}
$$

**Further reading**

As mentioned by [4er](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/52/4er) in a [comment](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables/38#comment282_38) below this answer: *"for quadratic functions of many binary variables, you can often do better than to linearize each product of variables separately"*. Some suggested references are:

1. F. Glover and E. Woolsey (1973). [Further reduction of zero-one polynomial programming problems to zero-one linear programming problems](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.21.1.156). *Operations Research* 21 156-161.
2. F. Glover (1975). [Improved Linear Integer Programming Formulations of Nonlinear Integer Problems](https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.22.4.455). *Management Science* 22 455-460.
3. M. Oral and O. Kettani (1992). [A linearization procedure for quadratic and cubic mixed-integer problems](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.40.1.S109). *Operations Research* 40 S109-S116.
4. W.P. Adams and R.J. Forrester (2005). [A simple recipe for concise mixed 0-1 linearizations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.orl.2004.05.001). *Operations Research Letters* 33 55-61.

Comment: And in the general case, look at the McCormick relaxation. If someone is at CPAIOR next week, please write here anything of interest in Toby’s talk.

Comment: If you have a quadratic function of many binary variables, then you can often do better than to linearize each product of variables separately. I'll give some references in the next comment.

Comment: [1] F Glover and E Woolsey, Further reduction of zero-one polynomial programming problems to zero-one linear programming problems. Operations Research 21 (1973) 156-161. 

[2] Glover, F. Improved Linear Integer Programming Formulations of Nonlinear Integer Problems. Management Science 22 (1975) 455-460. 

[3] M Oral and O Kettani, A linearization procedure for quadratic and cubic mixed-integer problems. Operations Research 40 (1992) S109-S116. 

[4] WP Adams and RJ Forrester, A simple recipe for concise mixed 0-1 linearizations. Operations Research Letters 33 (2005) 55-61.

Comment: @4er is it oke if I add your paper suggestions to my answer such that they are better visible? Of course you will be mentioned :)

Comment: It's OK. Please go ahead and add them.

Comment: @EdwardLam: the slides of CPAIOR you are asking ("Products in Mixed Integer Programming") are vailable at: http://cpaior2019.uowm.gr/wp-content/uploads/CPAIOR_Achterberg.pdf

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think $z$ has to be specified as binary. It suffices to set $z$ as a continuous nonnegative variable.

Answer (score 25):

It is worth noting that this formulation can be derived somewhat automatically by writing the logical proposition in conjunctive normal form:
\begin{align*}
& z \iff x \wedge y \\
& \left(z \implies (x \wedge y)\right) \bigwedge \left((x \wedge y) \implies z\right) \\
& \left(\neg z \vee (x \wedge y)\right) \bigwedge \left(\neg(x \wedge y) \vee z\right) \\
& \left((\neg z \vee x) \wedge (\neg z \vee y)\right) \bigwedge \left((\neg x \vee \neg y) \vee z\right) \\
& (\neg z \vee x) \bigwedge (\neg z \vee y) \bigwedge (\neg x \vee \neg y \vee z) \\
& \left((1 - z) + x \ge 1\right) \bigwedge \left((1 - z) + y \ge 1\right) \bigwedge \left((1 - x) + (1 - y) + z \ge 1\right) \\
& (x \ge z) \bigwedge (y \ge z) \bigwedge (z \ge x + y - 1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you know the reason for all constraint obtained from the conjunctive normal form result in disaggregated family of constraints?

Comment: @AlexandreFrias I guess you could say it is a consequence of DeMorgan's law: $P \lor (Q \land R) \equiv (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$.

Answer (score 3):

As the first answer:

$$
\begin{align}
z &\leq x_i \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots, n.\\
z &\geq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (n-1).
\end{align}
$$

We should note that, the property holds for an aggregated version of these constraints (obtained from the sum of the $z \leq x_i \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots, n$.

$$ 
\begin{align}
n.z & \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \\
z & \geq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i -(n-1)
\end{align}
$$

I prefer to use less constraints.

Comment: The aggregated version is correct but weaker.  It is worth trying both ways.

Comment: When I use aggregated constraints in Facility Location Problem, ($\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij} \leq m.y_j $) in place of  ($x_{ij}\leq y_j$), the running time is faster, almost ever. I think simplex algorithm works better using less constraints due to the number of vertex in the polytope.

Comment: Yes, and cut generation probably finds the disaggregated constraints as needed.  It depends on the problem and instance, and so it is worth trying both ways.