# how to linearize the full model for TSP quadratic formulation?

Tags: linearization, traveling-salesman

I tried to solve this problem but I failed, please how to linearized full model.
[image: TSP]

Answer (score 1):

You can linearize a product of binary variables by introducing a new nonnegative variable and linear constraints, as shown [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).  In the present case, you can exploit the fact that the product appears only in the objective with a nonnegative objective coefficient.  So only one additional linear constraint (instead of three) is needed per product:
$$z_{k,i,j} \ge y_{k,i} + y_{k+1,j} - 1$$
The linearized objective function is then
$$\sum_{i,j} d_{i,j} \sum_k z_{k,i,j}.$$

Because of the original equality constraints, you can reduce the linearized problem size by using a single additional variable per edge:
$$z_{i,j} \ge y_{k,i} + y_{k+1,j} - 1$$
with linearized objective function
$$\sum_{i,j} d_{i,j} z_{i,j}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your time.