# How to transform this logical if-then constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization, logical-constraints

Consider the binary variables $x, y, z \in \{0,1\}$.

I'd like to formulate the two if-then constraints:

$$ x + y \geq 2 \implies z = 0, \tag{1} $$
$$ x + y \leq 1 \implies z = 1. \tag{2} $$

Constraint (1) can be formulated as

$$
x + y \leq 2 - z.
$$

How to proceed for (2) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, for the first constraint you can use:
$$
x+y+z \le 2
$$

For the second one, it might be easier to model the contraposition:
$$
z=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x+y \ge 2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x=y=1
$$

This yields:
$$
1-z  \le x \\
1-z  \le y
$$

Answer (score 5):

You want to linearize $xy=1-z$. See https://or.stackexchange.com/a/473/500 for a somewhat automatic derivation of a linearization for $xy=z$ via conjunctive normal form. You can then replace $z$ with $1-z$ in the resulting constraints.