# Equivalence between constraints in ILP

Tags: integer-programming, constraint, combinatorial-optimization, linearization, logical-constraints

Let's have binary variables $x$ and $y$. I'd like to define a helping binary variable $z$ such that
$$ z = 1 \; \;\; \mathrm{iff} \; \; \; x + y = 2.$$
If I wanted to express the equivalence between binary variables $a$ and $b$, I would simply convert them into a conjunctive normal form:
$$ a \Leftrightarrow b \equiv (a \Rightarrow b) \land (b \Rightarrow a) \equiv 
(\lnot a \lor b) \land (\lnot b \lor a)$$
and do a standard SAT $\to$ ILP conversion:
$$ (1 -a) + b \geq 1, $$
$$ (1 - b) + a \geq 1. $$
Now let's try to substitute $a \to (z = 1)$ and $b \to (x + y = 2)$ into the CNF:
$$ (\lnot (z = 1) \lor (x + y = 2)) \land (\lnot (x + y = 2) \lor (z = 1)). $$
Since we can't use inequalities, we can rewrite the equalities as follows
$$ (\lnot (z \geq 1) \lor (x + y \geq 2)) \land (\lnot (x + y \geq 2) \lor (z \geq 1)) $$
and then we can simply negate the inequalities
$$ ((z \leq 0) \lor (x + y \geq 2)) \land ((x + y \leq 1) \lor (z \geq 1)). $$
Now, my idea was to use the fact that the logical AND is implicit within the constraints and that we can emulate logical OR between the inequalities using big $M$. Let's define helping variables $a_1$ and $a_2$.
$$ z \leq  \mathrm{M}a_1, $$
$$ x + y + \mathrm{M}(1 - a_1) \geq 2, $$
$$ x + y \leq 1 + Ma_2, $$
$$ z + M(1 - a_2) \geq 1. $$
Now this won't work since we could just use $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 0$ and there would be no constraint on $z$.

My idea is that we would somehow need to connect the lefthand side of the logical AND with the righthand side.

*Was my approach correct up until the point right before the last conversion?*

*How would one go about expressing the logical rules between entire equalities and inequalities in general?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you need all this machinery. I would write:

$$ \begin{aligned} & z=0 \iff 0 \le x+ y \le 1 \\
                   &  z=1 \iff 2 \le x+ y \le 2 \end{aligned} $$

or $$ 2z \le x+y \le 1 + z $$

(Actually Rob's answer is better than this: use $z=xy$ and linearize that using $z\le x$, $z \le y$ and $z\ge x+y-1$. That is tighter. In fact it is so tight that we can relax $z$ to be continuous between 0 and 1).

Comment: This is correct but can be strengthened by disaggregating $2z \le x+y$.

Comment: What did you do with the inequalities to obtain the final one?

Comment: Yes, 100% correct. We should use that. But is it still needed these days? I believe some of this disaggregation is done automatically. We can even write $z=xy$. My usual early morning "bad" formulations often do just as good as the good ones.

Comment: Yes, the strengthened version is often obtained dynamically in cut generation, but it is worth trying both ways.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the final inequality. Did you sum them up and somehow substituted for $z$?

Comment: No. $z=0 (1) \implies L=0 (2)$ is obviously the same as $L=2z$. Similar, $z=0(1) \implies U= 1(2)$ is the same as $U=1+z$. I can do this before my morning coffee (but then my capabilities stop).

Comment: Ok, now I see it but what makes me a little nervous is that I'm not sure if it's going to be this easy to see with a more complicated expression. I was looking for a more algorithmic and generally appliable process. What you did is that you took two piecewise functions and "guessed" the expression that would fit all the outputs which is fine but I can't be sure that it would be easy to see in a more complicated example.

Comment: Note that indicator constraints can simplify things. Most capable solvers support this.

Answer (score 4):

For binary variables $x$ and $y$, notice that $x+y=2$ is equivalent to $xy=1$, so you want to linearize $z=xy$.  I gave a derivation via conjunctive normal form in my answer here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/473/500

Comment: Nice, I'll have a look at that, but what if the epxression was something that was not obvious like this? Is there a general way of converting the equivalence of two inequalities into constraints?

Comment: How general do you want? Are you asking how to model $f(x)\le a \iff g(x)\le b$, where $f$ and $g$ are linear functions of variable $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $a$ and $b$ are constants?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. If there is a nicer way of doing it there are only binary variables or whatever, than that could also be useful.

Comment: OK, please open a separate question for that.

Comment: I already asked that in the question and in the title. I just chose some random constraints to ilustrate what I wanted and to show my attempt to solving it.

Comment: See my new question and answer here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j

Answer (score 1):

You can't let $a_1=1$ and $a_2=0$, because it will enforce $x+y \geq 2$ and $x+y \leq 1$, which is infeasible. That is the connection between the two new variables. So your model is totally correct but maybe not efficient.

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice that. So I guess now I can use the conversion of constraints into CNF whenever I feel lost. Good to know! Although I'm glad I read other answer as they gave me more insight into the problem. The fact that it is equivalent to linearizing $z = xy$ is just a pure coincidence as I made the example up.