# How to model a binary variable?

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, linearization, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I am trying to find a constraint for the following relationship, but am failing a bit at it right now. I want to find a linear constraint that does the following. The binary variable $switch_{ot}$ is to be introduced. It should always take the value 1, if the variable $lamp_{ot}$ was $=0$ in every of the periods $t-\tau$ to $t-1$. Otherwise $switch_{ot}=0$ shall be valid. How do I model something like this?

Comment: Do you mean “if the variable $lamp_{ot’}=0$ for *one* $t-\tau\leq t’\leq t-1$” or “if the variables $lamp_{ot’}=0$ for *all* $t-\tau\leq t’\leq t-1$”

Comment: Woopsie. I meant for all.

Comment: Are the "lamp" variables binary? If not, what are their domains?

Comment: Yes they are. Both are binary

Answer (score 3):

In other words, you want to linearize this relationship:
$$\text{switch}_{ot} \iff \bigwedge_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} \lnot \text{lamp}_{ou}$$

Or as a product:
$$\text{switch}_{ot} = \prod_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} (1 - \text{lamp}_{ou})$$

Because $\text{lamp}_{ou}$ is binary, so is its "complement" $1 - \text{lamp}_{ou}$, and the [usual linearization of a product of binary variables](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables) yields:
\begin{align}
\text{switch}_{ot} &\le 1 - \text{lamp}_{ou} &&\text{for $u \in \{t-\tau, \dots, t-1\}$} \tag1\label1\\
\text{switch}_{ot} &\ge \sum_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} (1 - \text{lamp}_{ou}) - \tau + 1 \tag2\label2
\end{align}

Of course, \eqref{2} can be simplified as
$$\text{switch}_{ot} \ge 1 - \sum_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} \text{lamp}_{ou}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Rob is great. Another way to model this with fewer constraints needed is the following:

\begin{alignat}1
(1- \text{switch}_{ot}) &\le \sum_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} \text{lamp}_{ou} 
\tag{1}\label{1A}\\
M \cdot (1- \text{switch}_{ot}) &\ge \sum_{u=t-\tau}^{t-1} \text{lamp}_{ou}  \tag{2} \label{2A}
\end{alignat}

Where $M$ is a large enough number. In your case this might be $\tau$.
If all $\text{lamp}_{ou}$ variables are $0$, equation \eqref{1A} makes sure that the switch variable is 1. If any $\text{lamp}_{ou}$ is greater $0$, \eqref{2A} states that the switch variable must be 0.

Comment: This is also correct.  Your (1) is my (2), and your (2) is an aggregation of my (1).  Yes, $M=\tau$ is valid.

Comment: You are right. Calling this a "different way" is maybe not the most correct statement ;)