# How can one model a binary variable?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, constraint, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I am looking for the formulation of a constraint that does the following. I want to introduce a new binary variable $\kappa_{it}$ that takes the value 1 if the sum of the other binary variable $\omega_{it}$ is greater than or equal to the number $N_{\max}$ by time $t$. Otherwise, it is to become zero. My suggestion would be:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{t}\omega_{ik}\le N_{\max} + M \cdot \kappa_{it}\\
N_{\max}+\mu\le\sum_{k=1}^{t}\omega_{ik}+\left( 1-\kappa_{it} \right) \cdot M $$

where $\mu$ is a small value. Is that correct?

Comment: This looks correct to me. A small suggestion. Since you are dealing with all the binaries, $\mu$ can just be 1.

Comment: The text of the question says $\kappa_{it}$ should be 1 if the sum is greater than *or equal to* $N_{max}.$ The formulation (with $\mu=1$) would be for *greater than* $N_{max}.$

Comment: [Related](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/10473/8)

Answer (score 7):

You want to enforce
$$
\sum_{k=1}^t \omega_{ik} \ge N_{max} \iff \kappa_{it}=1
$$
Or equivalently
\begin{align}
\left( \kappa_{it}=1 \implies \sum_{k=1}^t \omega_{ik} \ge N_{max}  \right) 
\wedge
\left( \kappa_{it}=0 \implies \sum_{k=1}^t \omega_{ik} \le N_{max}-1\right)
\end{align}

You can enforce this with big-M constraints:
$$
N_{max}\kappa_{it} \le \sum_{k=1}^t \omega_{ik} \le N_{max}-1+(t+1-N_{max})\kappa_{it}
$$